# Why cant I change the color of a JButton?

Tags: java, colors, jbutton, foreground

I'm trying to change the color of a JButton and after some googling I found that button.setForeground(Color a) should do this, but for some reason it doesn't work. The button color isn't changing.

This is my code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class test extends JFrame{

    public test(){

        super();
        setSize(100,100);
        setVisible(true);
        JButton x = new JButton();
        x.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        add(x);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new test();
    }

}
```

I also tried setBackground(Color a) but this just changed the background of the actual button, not the color *inside* it.

What am I missing?

Comment: The default foreground is BLACK. Try another color.

Comment: Also, class names (even for testing) should start with an upper case character. Components should be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is made visible. Learn/use proper techniques even for short demo programs so you get in good habits for your real programs.

Comment: @camickr if the default color is black then why is the button blue? I just tried green and nothing happened. Also, I wrote this class specifically so I could write it here, the project i'm working on involves multiple classes so I thought this would be easier, but yes you're right.

Comment: What do you mean by "color inside it"? What is the look you are going for? It sounds like your problem might be with the Java Look and Feel.

Comment: @FuryCompteurs I'm talking about the color of the actual button.

Comment: @Swailem95, the default foreground (ie, the text) is BLACK, The default background is a blue gradient. What else are you trying to change?

Comment: @camickr when I tried using setBackground, it changed the color outside the button, but now it changed the color inside. I must have used it wrong the first time. All's good now. Thank you all.

Comment: You have to call `validate()` on the frame after `add(…)` to ensure that the layout manager adapts the bounds of the button to fit into the frame. Without it, the button has its initial zero size and you see the frame’s background, but note that if the user resizes the frame manually, it will trigger a validation as well…

Answer (score 1):

Check out JButton documentation:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html
and you can change the Background color Using :

```
btn.setBackground(Color.BLACK);//Black By Default
btn.setForeground(Color.GRAY);//Set as a Gray Colour
```